# Spring cache updates when read value updated in method

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cache

I am facing spring cache issue as explained below. Checking if anyone faced similar issue or any workaround available. I am using generic cache for simple usecases.

Spring cache code below reads from DB and caches:

```
    @Cacheable("all-items")
    public List<ItemData> getAllItems() {
       //DB fetch here
    }
```

Another method reads from cache:

```
   public List<ItemData> getFilterData(String filter) {
      List<ItemData> items = templateItemRepo.getAllItems();
      // more code here to apply filter
      staticItems.forEach(x -> {
            items.removeIf(i -> i.getKey().equals(x)); //after this line, cache gets updated instead of maintaining its original data
      });
   }
```

After read items from cache is modified locally in method, surprisingly cache also gets updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What were you expecting to happen in this case?

Were you expecting that the `List` of `ItemData` objects (the cached data in this case) would not be modified?

Without your exact configuration (and code) it would be inaccurate to say for sure, but based on your description it is somewhat easy to conjecture what is happening here.

For one, you say you are using a "generic cache".  Well, in Spring, when you do not explicitly declare and configure a specific caching provider, such as Redis, Hazelcast, Apache Geode (GemFire), or otherwise (see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-store-configuration) or [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/io.html#io.caching.provider), and specifically, [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/io.html#io.caching.provider.generic)), then what Spring gives you is a `ConcurrentMap` cache implementation, by default (a `ConcurrentHashMap` to be precise; see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/io.html#io.caching.provider.simple)), where cached values are stored in-memory, in the same JVM process as your Spring [Boot] application.

Second, assuming `templateItemRepo` refers to a Repository type containing your `@Cacheable` `getAllItems()` method, then the first time `getAllItems()` is called from another managed bean in the Spring container, such as your type containing the `getFilterData(:String)` method, the `@Cacheable` `getAllItems()` Repository method will be executed and the returned `List` of `ItemData` objects will be cached under a simple key.

> NOTE: A simple key is used in this case since the `@Cacheable` `getAllItems()` Repository method has no parameters. See [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-default-key) for more details.

Thereafter, each subsequent call to the `@Cacheable` `getAllItems()` Repository method will always return the **same**, cached `List` of `ItemData` objects given the underlying `Cache` implementation is a `ConcurrentMap`.

By example, what your "all-items" `Cache` contains is the following, single cache entry (key/value):

`<simple-key> : List<ItemData>`

All subsequent calls to the `@Cacheable` `getAllItems()` Repository method always uses the same simple key and always returns the exact same object reference to the `List` of `ItemData` stored in the "all-items" `Cache`.

Using a caching provider like Redis, Hazelcast or Apache Geode can lead to a different behavior since these data stores handle data differently.

For instance, Apache Geode has the ability to configure *copy-on-read* semantics, meaning when the value (e.g. `List` of `ItemData`) is read (`cache.get(key)`) from the "all-items" `Cache`, what you get back is a true (deep) "copy" of the `List` and all of its `ItemData` objects, even if the "all-items" `Cache` were local, in-memory of the same JVM process as your Spring [Boot] application.

If your caching provider is used in client/server topology, then the `List` and its contents (`ItemData` objects) will be necessarily serialized between client and server, and once again, what you will get back is a "copy" of the `List` (assuming the `ItemData` type was serializable in some capacity).

Each caching provider will offers different capabilities in this regard and other factors that can significantly affect the data is eviction and expiration policies.

If you want to implement similar behavior to a caching provider in your simple, "generic" cache arrangement , then you would need to make a [deep] copy of the `List`, manually.

Of course, you could create [*Adapter*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) (Wrapper) or [*Decorator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) implementations of the primary `Cache` ([Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/Cache.html)) and `CacheManager` ([Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/CacheManager.html)) interfaces from Spring's Cache Abstraction, which could handle this copying for you.  The Wrapper types would wrap the actual `Cache` and `CacheManager` interfaces from the actual caching provider, even when the simple `Cache` implementation backed by a `ConcurrentMap` is used.

However, when using a sophisticated caching provider, it is best to let the provider handle copying, serialization, among other things. Still, for testing simple cases, the above approach could prove useful.

Comment: By way of example, supporting my answer above, I wrote the following test class to demonstrate: https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/MutableSimpleCacheValueIntegrationTests.java.

Comment: Additionally, I should point out that rather than use the Decorator / Adapter (Wrapper) approach I described above, it is possible using the simple Cache (ConcurrentMapCache) to configure a `SerializationDelegate` (see source: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.3.16/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/concurrent/ConcurrentMapCache.java#L54). When configured, the value will be cached by value, and not by reference (default). Of course ...

Comment: This all depends on your `o.s.core.serializer.Serializer` implementation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/serializer/Serializer.html) and `o.s.core.serializer.Deserializer` implementation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/serializer/Deserializer.html) to which the `SerializerDelegate` delegates (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.3.16/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/serializer/support/SerializationDelegate.java#L39-L41).

Comment: By default, the `ConcurrentMapCache` does not configure serialization and therefore is copy by reference, or in other words, return the exact object reference to the value stored in the `Cache`.

Comment: Yes, it is copy by reference. Found this if anyone needs - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18331